# Ati driver Issue

Tags: ati

I have serious issue with my laptop graphic card.

I have this graphic card:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] [1002:9851] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:22c2]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0800000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
    Memory at f0600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at f0680000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

If I try to use the default open source driver, I can't use 2 monitor or a correct resolution .

If I use the AMD driver on every release , I have serious issue , specially with chrome.

Can someone help me to use the correct driver ?

Comment: I have been facing this issue and it seems that the ATI driver is just not working correctly, as some of its functionality used in Unity is flawed and (for me) connecting a second monitor results in both monitors having a scattered view, impossible to navigate through. The only solution I found myself was not using ATI driver and enabling integrated card drivers instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

the ppa edgers will give you some updates for the fglrx.
then reinstall the fglrx.

```
sudo su
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
```

You can also use fgrlxinfo to see your opengl and catalyst version.

Comment: apt-get install fglrx-installer 

Unable to find fglrx-installer

fgrlxinfo 

command not found

Comment: oh, sorry fglrx-installer is the name of the launchpad url, just do the rest, my mistake. You can check the names and what they are for, here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer